# Segmentation Fault(core dumped) when an int variable is initialized

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, initialization

Segmentation fault appearing due to initializing of the variable 'b'. Someone please help me on this.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(){
    char *z[20], *x, *y = {"abcd"};
    int i, j, b = 4;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
         for (j = 0 ; j < b ; j++) {
             *(x + j) = *(y + j + i);
             z[i] = x;
             printf("%s", z[i]);
             printf("\n");
         }
         b--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Honest question? Why are such questions downvoted?

Answer (score 5):

You dereference `x` which is not initialized anywhere and hence is an invalid pointer

```
*(x + j) = *(y + j + i);
```

Possible solution:

- Declare `x` as an array, like

  ```
  char x[5];
  ```

  and, `nul` terminate it before printing it, like

  ```
  x[j]     = y[i + j];
  x[1 + j] = '\0';
  ```

One more thing, is that every `z[i]` that is initialized, will point to the same data, i.e. to the array `x` if you apply my suggested solution.

Answer (score 3):

You already got the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31073681/2173917) from Mr. [Iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983495/iharob) for your question, just to elaborate a bit, I though of adding mine.

In your question, you mentioned like

> *...when an `int` variable is initialized*

This statement is wrong. There is no issue with `int` variable initializations (`i = 0`, `j = 0` and `b = 4`). The issue here is with the inappropriate usage of `x`.

In your code, `x` is of type `char *`, i.e., it is a pointer to an `char`. Now, by saying

```
 *(x + j) = <some value>
```

you're *trying to* assign a value to the `char` that `x` (or, rather `x + j`, in general) *points to*. Fine, but wait, wait, what does `x` (or, `x + j`) actually point to at present?

Answer: `x` itself is  not initialized explicitly, so it does not point to any valid memory where you can write the value. Standards specify, trying to read from or write to an uninitlalized memory location invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is one of the side effects of UB.

To avoid, you need to allocate memory to `x`  first (so that it points to a valid memory location) and then put the value to the memory location it *points to*. You can use [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family of functions to get the memory allocation done.

Comment: I rather suspect that the OP might think that `x` points to the memory address of the start of a string `abcd`, so this is a useful answer.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Thank you. Glad you found it's useful. :-)